# Pong movement not smooth

Tags: processing, pong

I want to make a pong game in processing. But the movement of the ball was not very smooth. I tried changing the frame rate and decrease the speed of the ball, but then the movement speed seems to be not constant. Could this be a performance problem? Am I doing something wrong, or is processing maybe not the right thing, even for simple games? (My goal was to try out processing.js and make a game that runs without a plugin). Here is my code:

```java
// Colorset
color scrBG;
color bastards;

// Border for the Paddle
int border;

// The Paddle
int padWid;
int padHei;
float padX;
float padY;

// The Ball
float ballX;
float ballY;
int ballRad;

int speed;
float velX;
float velY;

boolean playing = false;



void setup()
{
  border = 5;

  scrBG = #EEEEEE;
  bastards = #FFF0EB;

  padWid = 80;
  padHei = 10;
  ballRad = 15;
  speed = 5;
  velX = velY = speed;

  size(800, 600);
  background(scrBG);
  noStroke();
  noCursor();
  //frameRate(100);
  smooth();
}

void draw()
{

  background(bastards);drawPaddle();
  drawBall();
}

void drawBall()
{

  if(!playing)
  {
    ballX = padX+padWid/2;
    ballY = height-border-padHei-ballRad/2-2;
  }
  else
  {
if(ballY > height)
{
  ballOut();
}

if(ballY > padY && ballX < padX + padWid && ballX > padX)
{
  velY = -velY;
  ballY = padY-ballRad-1;
}
if(ballX < ballRad)
{
  velX = -velX;
  ballX = ballRad+1;
}
if(ballX > width-ballRad)
{
  velX = -velX;
  ballX = width-ballRad-1;
}
if(ballY < ballRad)
{
  velY = -velY;
  ballY = ballRad+1;
}


ballY += velY;
ballX += velX;   
  }

  fill(0);
  ellipse(ballX, ballY, ballRad*2, ballRad*2);

}

void drawPaddle()
{
  padX = constrain(mouseX, border, width-padWid-border);
  padY = height-padHei-border;

  fill(0);
  rect(padX, padY, padWid, padHei);
}

void startLevel()
{
  playing = true;
}

void resetLevel()
{
  playing = false;
}

void ballOut()
{
  playing = false;
}

void mouseClicked()
{
  if(playing)
  {
    resetLevel();
  }
  else
  {
    startLevel();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your frameRate seems quit high to me. 30 frames is normally a good speed for smooth animation in things like Processing and Flash. I'd also change all my ints to floats as floats are better for smooth animation.

The next thing I'd look at is adding in some easing, this may smooth it out. See this info on processing.org:

[www.processing.org/learning/basics/easing.html](http://processing.org/learning/basics/easing.html)

and have a play.

Comment: Thanks for responding. As you can see, the high framerate is commented out. I just tested it. I used floats for everything, that has to do with the balls movement. I tried making everything a float, but it doesn't make any difference. Just to clearify: There is no big problem, I just think that the movement isn't completely constant.

Comment: If you comment out frameRate then your script will run as fast as your computer will go. So commenting out the high frameRate might actually be making it run faster than 100FPS. Check your CPU usage. I use a mac and I've noticed that processing can be oddly heavy on it. When I googled it a while back I found i wasn't the only one who had this problem.

Comment: I did that too, but the ball movement ist still shakey. Can you see that, too? (I'm using windows. I dont think cpu usage should be a problem, its a new computer)

Comment: I get a slight judder but nothing much. I'd set the frameRate to 40 as it's enough for the animation and should limit the tax on your CPU, so that would hopefully get rid of one possible cause of the ball being shakey. The next thing I'd look at is adding in some easing, this may smooth it out. See this info on processing.org: http://processing.org/learning/basics/easing.html  and have a play.

Comment: I will try that too. If it works or not, I think my question is answered. Thank you very much!

Comment: +1. But I believe you should add the easing part in the answer, as one might not read the comments.